# Implementing beq and bne MIPS instruction in java

Tags: java, mips

Can anyone give me an idea on how to implement beq and bne instruction in Java

Input file is 32 bit binary input in hex

Comment: Did you already implement `jmp` instructions?

Comment: No, I am not sure on how to implement any jump instruction. I know how to code some of beq, but I don't know how to jump to address and execute instruction at that address

Comment: how does the program advance to the next instruction if there is no jump or branch? Is there some instruction pointer that gets incremented. A jump/branch would reset that pointer.

Comment: I am using for loop to read each line of instruction encoded in hex. Yes, its true that I can reset the counter, but how do I tell program to execute particular instruction located at address programming jumped to.

Comment: You need a way to jump around, not just read line by line. You probably have to read the whole program into a memory buffer first. And make sure you exactly match the memory layout that MIPS expects (such as instruction length).

Comment: Yes, my program does read each line first and stores it into hashmap, but from what I know target address for beq is only 16 bit(4 hex), but originally each instruction is referenced by 8 hex address

Comment: Why can't you then go the address you need to jump to?

Comment: Because my original address to instruction is represented by 32 bits (8 hex) but target in bew can only be up to 16 bits

Comment: But it still refers to some address. You need to do the proper calculation (might be relative addressing, too) and conversion.

Comment: Yes, it would refer to some address, but that address wouldn't be in the memory, because all the address stored in memory during the initial step is 32 bits, and since it wouldn't be in memory my jump would execute nothing

Comment: The 16 bit jump target is a relative address that has to offset by the instruction counter. It will be negative for backwards jumps, for example. Do that calculation to arrive at your new (32bit) address.

Comment: Thanks, I made it work